# Load text to datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have point files like:
[image: Example point file]

I have created code that allows users to select the files from a dialog box and it will populate the data to the gridview.

```
private void cmdload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("Point");
    table.Columns.Add("X");
    table.Columns.Add("Y");
    table.Columns.Add("Z");
    table.Columns.Add("R");
    table.Columns.Add("A");
    table.Columns.Add("B");
    table.Columns.Add("C");
    Stream myStream = null;
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\\"; 
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "Data Files (*.PNT)|*.PNT";
    openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
    openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        try
        {
            if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
            {
                using (myStream)
                {
                    string filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                    using (var reader = File.OpenText(filename)) 
                    {
                        string line;
                        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            string[] parts = line.Split(' ');
                            table.Rows.Add(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2], parts[3], parts[4], parts[5], parts[6], parts[7]);
                        }
                        dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex) // you need to add the catch block if yo are using try block
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
        }

    }
}
```

This code works fine, however the datagridview does not display the value.

[image: Example output]

Comment: the rows and columns are getting created only you don't see the value...right? Are you creating the datagridview rows through code.

Comment: @Junaith Yes, I created the column by default in datagridview properties. And when I select the files, I can see the rows are increasing according to the data rows in the point files, just there's no value display in the gridview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not creating the `DataGridView` columns through code then you have to set the `DataPropertyName` of the `DataGridViewColumn` to the columns ids in the `DataTable`.

Sample code:

```
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn col1 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
col1.Name = "Point";
col1.HeaderText = "Point";
col1.DataPropertyName = "Point";
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col1)
```

The other way is to set `AutoGenerateColumns` property to true to create the required columns automatically and bind the data to the `DataTable`. By this you don't have to create columns through code like in the above sample code.

```
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. But since I'm newbie, I just can't get it what you mean. Can you guide me a little bit more?

Comment: @Ren - The above is just sample code. Check in your designer whether you have created columns like in the sample code. If you see then just set the `DataPropertyName` property for that column. if not you check the whether `AutoGenerateColumns` is set to false and change it to true.